# adding just a folder to a git repo but dont remove other folders that already exist?

Tags: python-3.x, gitpython

I'm automating a specific task where a new folder is added to a git repo.
im copying the .git folder from a working git push.

im staging all the things in the folder I want to push, then when I push it it goes fine, but the 5 other folders that were in the repo on the server are gone and only my new staged folder is there. once the folder I make is there it gets deleted locally, so literally I just want to add this folder to the repo so its available to others.

I don't want to have to download the entire repo each time just to push one folder up. Is there a way to do this?

```
def gitPush(commit_message:str):
    if not checkExists((staging_root) + '.git'):
        return(".git folder not found, cannot push.")
    else:
        repo = Repo(staging_root + '.git')
        repo.git.add(all=True)
        repo.index.commit(commit_message)
        origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
        origin.push('master')
```

thx.

Comment: What library did you get the `Repo` class from?

Comment: from git import Repo

Comment: Assuming that means GitPython then you shouldn't add the `.git` portion of the directory to the constructor, just point to the path that *contains* the `.git` directory.

Comment: doing that gives the exact same results